# does adverb "much" modify an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

[In dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/much)

> Much adv. more, most
>
> 1. To a great degree or extent: much smarter.
> 2. Just about; almost: much the same.
> 3. Frequently; often: doesn't get out much.

But, *does adverb "**much**" modify an adjective?*

Ex: I have never heard anyone say "**This house is much clean**" but "**This house is much cleaner**" is ok.

SO, *"**much**" can not modify "adjective" but "comparative adjective"?*

Comment: You are right, we don't use much in front of adjectives, but we can do with comparative adjectives.

Comment: You can say "This house is much cleaner" if you compare it with some other house. "This house is much cleaner than the previous one". But you can't say "This house is much clean"

Comment: @Khan You've thought my thought.

Comment: "Much" doesn't modify other adverb (very fast, not much fast) or adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> much

though usually not followed by an adjective

> <s>much red</s>  *(incorrect)*
>   <s>much cold</s>  *(incorrect)*

can be in certain situations

> I'm much concerned about...
>   *I am worried about...*

or with "very much"

> [I'm *very much aware* about...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150754/differences-between-very-and-very-much-as-adjective-modifiers)

Comment: I have a question about the last case of the explanation where you took ***I'm very much aware about...*** as an example sentence. Can it apply to normal adjectives like **beautiful, happy, red, cold**, for instance, ***She is very much beautiful*** or ***She is beautiful very much***?

Comment: Between the two choices: **She is very much beautiful.** would be understood, however **She is very much a beauty.** would be correct.

Comment: @But do you mean, even though***She is very much beautiful*** would be understood, it is an incorrect and weird sentence?

Comment: It is awkward, a native would probably not use it. Rather, to the question "**Is she beautiful?**", one might say "**She is very much so.**" but a native would probably just say "**Yes, she is very beautiful.**"

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter. I am sorry to keep bothering you, but is ***She is very much so*** also an awkward, incorrect expression? I just wonder if it is as incorrect as ***She is very much beautiful*** is. :)

Comment: "***She is very much beautiful.***"  is always awkward and should be "***She is very beautiful.***". "***She is very much so.***" only works in the context of being asked "***Is she beautiful?***".

Comment: Thank you for the continuous answers. Although I am deeply sorry to keep asking you similar questions, I really feel like I need to check how normal ***She is very much so*** as a reply for ***Is she beautiful*** sound. Do you mean in that context it is totally normal and not weird at all?

Comment: Correct in that circumstance not strange at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation, Peter. I appreciate all your help.